# Is my Milwaukee drill defective?

Tags: electrical, drill, studs, rough-in

I have a Milwaukee M12 Fuel hammer drill I purchased in July. Last week I was drilling holes through studs with a brand new 5/8” auger bit and the drill was constantly stopping due to overload protection. I was not putting a ton of force into the drill, trying to let it do the work. I’ve tried multiple batteries and both produced same result.

Is this normal for an M12 Fuel drill to stall out when drilling studs? Or is there a problem with my drill?

Answer (score 3):

What size battery do you have? When using large bits the drill draws a high amperage the smaller batteries just cannot sustain a heavy load. For example a 1 amp hour drill may be able to drill an inch but jump to a 4 amp hour or larger and it may not over heat and shutdown at all, I found this especially true with my battery band saw, trying to cut 2" pipe my small batteries just could not keep up but the big ones made cut after cut with no problems.

Comment: I have the smaller 2ah batteries. I didn’t think about larger capacity battery affecting performance. Appreciate the insight.